# Routing between two react applications with separate BrowserRouters registered using single-spa

Tags: reactjs, react-router, url-routing, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have registered three react applications using single-spa like this:

```
registerApplication("core", () => import("./core.js"), () => true, customProps)

registerApplication("app1", () => import("./app1.js"), () => true, customProps)
registerApplication("app2", () => import("./app2.js"), () => true, customProps)
```

Each of these applications have their own BrowserRouters.

app1.index.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/app1" render={() => <Component1 />} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

app2.index.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/app2" render={() => <Component2 />} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

In core.index.js I have the navigation bar which should route to /app1 and /app2

```
<Link to"/app1">App1</Link>
<Link to"/app2">App2</Link>
```

First of all I'm seeing error for using Link outside BrowserRouter (in core.index.js). Even if I try to enclose Link tags inside BrowserRouter in core.index.js, it is only changing the URL on click of links but the view is not changing.

Comment: Since you are using separate routers, then you would need to link to them like it was an external page (ie `<a href="/someapp">Some app link</a>` . You should only use one router so that resources don't need to be re-downloaded.

Comment: Hi @SILENT thanks for your response. But app1 and app2 are two different applications which are coming from two different repos. I cannot restrict either app1 or app2 from using their own routers.
Also, if I use <a href=""> then the page would get reloaded, which is not the expected behaviour.

Comment: In order to change views, it would need to be using the same router. Since its not, you have no alternative other than a redirect.

Comment: Even if I try to restrict the apps from not different routers, single-spa is rendering each application in separate Context.Provider. So, if I add the router in my core app, the other apps are not coming under the core app as the single-spa renders under separate Context.Provider. Hence I get error of using <Route> (which is used in app1 and app2) outside <BrowserRouter>
Can I bring all the applications under one single HOC in order to have Router in the global level in my core app?

Comment: As long as they share the same context, yes.

Comment: They are not currently sharing same context. They are under separate contexts. Can all the apps be brought under one single context? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You would merge the apps into one.

Comment: Can you please provide me an example snippet to merge the apps to come under one single context?

Comment: Your sample code already shows the implementation. Combine app1 and app2 under the same context.

Comment: Combining app1, app2 and core itself is not happening if I register the applications using singlespa.registerApplication